What is the equivalent JavaScript syntax to Python's rawstring syntax r"" (instead of rf"")?
In Javascript, we can use the ES6 raw string String.raw`raw text` to form a raw string, but it uses the template string syntax at the same time.
If I want to store the string "${a}\\${b}, with \\n", I cannot use something such as String.raw`\${a}\\${b}, with \n` or String.raw"${a}\${b}, with \n" (of course, the tag function is not used this way).
Is there a prettier way to write it, similar to writing r"{a}\{b}, with \n" (no $ in Python format syntax) in Python?

In a nutshell: no.

I do not know why you want to avoid template strings. But if you want a closer syntax to Python, you can use a Proxy:


const r = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(t, p, r) {
        return p /*.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') optional*/
              .replace(/\n/g, '\\n')
              .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')
              .replace(/\t/g, '\\t')
              .replace(/\v/g, '\\v')
              .replace(/\f/g, '\\f');
    }
})
let result = r["\n\nhaha"]
console.log(result);
let templateRaw = String.raw`\n\nhaha`;
console.log(templateRaw)

console.log(String.raw`{a}\{b}, with \n`)
console.log(r["{a}\\{b}, with \n"]) // here you have to escape the backlash



Idk, is that what you want? If yes, arrange the escapes inside the GET handler to your needs

Thanks, this looks very helpful to me
